# Is there any way to change the I2C slave device address on a Linux board?

Tags: linux, debian, udev, beagleboneblack, ioctl

Aim: setAddress in i2c Slave Devices software side.

example :
3 sensor with same address 0x29. through some method sensor1 to set 0x22, sensor2 to set 0x25, sersor3 to set 0x28.

info:
I have 3 similar devices with the same i2c address. i2c slave device is VL53L0X (TOF) sensor with BeagleBone Black debian os.
The communication occurs through `sys/ioctl.h` and `linux/i2c-dev.h`.

Example Code:

```c
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/i2c-dev.h>

ioctl(open("/dev/i2c-2", O_RDWR), I2C_SLAVE, 0x29);
```

thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The [datasheet for the VL53L0X](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/vl53l0x.pdf), pages 18-19, specifies that the I2C address of the device can be changed with a simple write operation to the appropriate register in the device. Note that I2C address 0x29 in your example is the same as 0x52 in the datasheet, but the datasheet address value is shifted one bit left to include the I2C read/write bit in the least significant bit position.

But since multiple VL52L0X devices will initially all have the same address, there must be a way to control the reset signal for each VL53L0X chip independently. The necessary process is described in the [AN4846 application note for the VL53L0X](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an4846-using-multiple-vl53l0x-in-a-single-design-stmicroelectronics.pdf). In short, there should be two GPIO pins wired to each VL53L0X chip individually, either directly or through some GPIO expander chip. You'll need to examine your hardware design to find out where these are routed in it.

The register number is indicated in the [C programming API package for VL50L0X](https://www.st.com/content/st_com_cx/en/products/embedded-software/imaging-software/stsw-img005.html) (free but requires registration with a valid email address). Look for `VL53L0X_REG_I2C_SLAVE_DEVICE_ADDRESS` in file `VL53L0X_1.0.4/Api/core/inc/vl53l0x_device.h` in the API package `en.STSW-IMG005_v1.0.4.zip`.